# Append different data depending on variable value

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have 2 lots of json data being loaded on the page.  I want to append a different list depending on what loaddata equals.

How can I do this?

In console.log myList equals myjson2 however I am getting an undefined error when I try and put `myList.forEach(createList);` in.

```
function createList(element, index, array) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute("data-rank",index);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(element['name']));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.setAttribute("id","test"); 
document.body.appendChild(ul);

var myjson1 = [{
    "name": "Tom",
    "rank": 1
},{
    "name": "Richard",
    "rank": 3
}];

var myjson2 = [{
    "name": "Kate",
    "rank": 1
},{
    "name": "Sarah",
    "rank": 3
}];

var loaddata=2;
var myList = "myjson" + loaddata;
console.log(myList);
//myList.forEach(createList); /* commented out as not working */
myjson1.forEach(createList); /* appends myjson1 list */
myjson2.forEach(createList); /* appends myjson2 list */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly what you are trying to do is

```
var myList = this["myjson" + loaddata];
```

However your `var myjson` needs to be declared in the global scope in order to work.